# Why are background images in css expressed as url but images in img can just be the path to the file

Tags: html, css, url, image

We had a designer do our html/css and while updating some code I noticed this:

`img` tags just reference the path to the image:

`<img src="/images/pic.png">`

But for css (with the `background` tag), it's specified using a url:

`header { height: 73px; background: url(/assets/maudi/nav.png); }`

What is the importance of `url`?

Comment: how else would the css parser know that you want `background: white` to be a file named `white` on the webserver v.s. simply being a color specification?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML doesn't have anywhere that can accept "a URL or something else".

CSS does. The `background` property being a prime example.

```
background: blue;
```

Is `blue` a color or a relative URL?

Comment: This isn't relevant: `background-image: url(/images/pic.png);` still requires the url() convention.

Comment: @Mash — It is relevant. Being inconsistent would be awful.

Comment: I had just thought afterwards that things like `-webkit-linear-gradient` can also be values for `background-image`, disregard my concern anyways.

Comment: @Mash isn't completely wrong, considering that they **could** have used position alone within grouped properties like `background` (and `-webkit-linear-gradient` was a later addition). It wouldn't be anywhere near as readable though, especially since `url(black)` is a perfectly good relative uri (from `http://example.net/s.css` it would reference `http://example.net/black`). It isn't even an unlikely name for a mostly black image used as a background.